# Squealing and chirp noise

Tags: power-steering

My Renault Megane scenic 1.4 has a squeaky and chirp sound and it also drips power steering fluid under the car on the floor it's visible. The cambelt also have a 2cm Crack on the edge of the belt. I identified all these things that should be fixed but I am not really sure what the cause is of the squealing and chirp noise.

[image: Renault Megane Scenic]

Comment: Are you sure it's the cambelt?  It could very well be the crack is in the drive belt for the power steering pump.  The cambelt isn't visible without the removal of a number of plastic covers.

Answer (score 1):

They are sounds due to a loose or slipping belt - sounds warning you that it needs maintenance. And that cambelt needs changing - a cheaper option than waiting for it to break.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @SolarMike if you are sure it is the cam belt which has a crack in it, you are best getting that changed before it breaks as it can ruin the engine if it does. I learnt that the hard way and it was cheaper to buy a replacement car than getting the engine repaired/replaced.

The squealing and chirping sound is likely to be the drive belt (sometimes referred to as the fan belt or alternator belt), which if that is what is cracked, ought to be changed rather than just tightened.

The fan/drive belt will be driving the water cooling pump, alternator and power steering pump. If it snaps, the heat inside your engine will rapidly increase and your coolant will rapidly rise in temperature towards boiling point.  Your power steering will likely fail too.

[image: image of a fitted fan/drive/alternator belt with annotations for powrr steering pump, alternator, water (cooling system) pump, air conditioning pump and belt tensioner pulley - rotate tensioner clockwise to release the tension as it is reverse threaded]

Replacing the fan/drive belt is the first thing I learnt to change and tighten myself. It is one of the cheapest and easiest things you can do and therefore shouldn't cost very much if you haven't got the tools and you employ a mechanic to do it.

The cam belt is a different matter though.  It is usually covered and care needs to be taken when removing it and replacing it with a new one.

As for the power steering fluid leak, that isn't necessarily urgent unless it is leaking a lot. However, it could get to the point where your power steering could become inefficient due to air getting into the hydraulic system. The belts however, are important to keep tight and in good condition.